# how to find ID of alot of view in a for loop using kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I made a custom day picker in a row of radio buttons inside a fragment that contains days of the month and the ID of each one is like something like this
`@+id/day_01` and `@+id/day_02`
and I want to add a text to each one that says the day name of the week like **WEN 05**
so first of all I want to find ids of each one in for loop and change the text of that view in the loop but don't know how to do that
part of my current code in my fragment is:

```
val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        
val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
val currentDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

val hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
val minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
val daysInMonth = c.getActualMaximum(month)

fun getMonth() {
    if (daysInMonth==29) {
        view.day_31.visibility = View.GONE
        view.day_30.visibility = View.GONE
    } else if (daysInMonth==30) {
        view.day_31.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}

getMonth()

for (i in 1 .. daysInMonth) {
    val dayOfMonth = GregorianCalendar(year, month, i)
    val day = dayOfMonth.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH).toString()
    view.day_"i".text = day
}
```

I don't know what todo about that part of `view.day_"i".text = day` but I want for example when
`i=3` the loop do something like this `view.day_03.text = "03"`

if you know a better way to make a custom date picker please show me that

Comment: You can find the answer very quickly with a simple google search. You can get here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#for-loops.                                                 for ((index, value) in array.withIndex()) {
    println("the element at $index is $value")
}

Comment: You can use `radiogroup.setoncheckedchangedlistener` to know which radio button is checked in the radiogroup.

Comment: Anytime you find yourself making more than a few identical views, you should stop and consider using RecyclerView instead of a bunch of duplicate views with IDs. That's not very maintainable.

Comment: @RazvanS. thanks but I know how to work with for loops, the thing I'm looking for is how to do the thing that I said in the last 3 lines of my question. how to write something like this    view.day_"i".text

Comment: @VenkateshTalacheeru okay thanks  I have to test it

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'm not good at working with recycler view too much, and I don't think there is too much difference. so there is no way to the thing that I want?

Comment: You can do it this way, I just don't recommend it. Projects become unmanageable and error prone when there is a lot of manual duplication of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the `getIdentifier()` function for getting item views by name. This method is discouraged, because it uses reflection, which negatively impacts performance. With only 31 days to handle, it's probably fine.

```
for (i in 1 .. daysInMonth) {
    //...
    val dayViewId = resources.getIdentifier("day_$i", "id", packageName)
    view.findViewById<TextView>(dayViewId).text = day
}
```

If you're in a Fragment, use `requireContext().packageName`.

By the way, the Calendar class is outdated and not intended for use in new projects. [See here for an explanation.](https://www.baeldung.com/migrating-to-java-8-date-time-api)

Comment: thanks, it worked. however, I consider what you said about my way. actually, I didn't find any other solution to make my date picker and because I'm not pro, my code definitely has a lot of problems but for now, I rather leave it like this and make it better in future